# the parameter of this function?

Tags: c++

```
bool horizontal_Check1(string** board){
for(int row=7; row>=0; row--){
    for(int col=0; col<=7; col++){
        if(board[row][col]=="|X|"&&board[row][col+1]=="|X|"&&board[row][col+2]=="|X|"&&board[row][col+3]=="|X|"){
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
return 0;}
```

When i try to build this function it shows the following error :

> error C2664: 'horizontal_Check1' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::string **'
>
> No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: the simple workaround is to use `std::vector< std::vector< std::string > >` and then pass by reference `bool horizontal_Check1(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& board)` or std::array if you have fixed dimensions

Comment: By assigning an array of pointers to its parameter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's especially important to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error came from where you call `horizontal_Check1` function. Maybe you passed just a `string` instance rather than double pointer of it?

```
string str = "random string";
horizontal_Check(str); // error
```

Calling code should be like this

```
string str[...][...];
// need conversion from array `string[...][...]` to pointer `string **`
horizontal_Check(&str[0]);
```

You intended to pass a 2-dimension array of strings to the function in C style. However with C++, I would go this way,

```
bool horizontal_Check1(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& board)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. A 2D string array is not a `string**`. Even after decay, the type ends up as `string(*)[N]`, where N is the second dimension.

Comment: It worked thanks so much :D

Comment: @chris I notice that pointers are not arrays, so I presented `string[][] is similar to string **` not `string[][] is string**`. I just couldn't come up with other expression.

Comment: Regardless, what you claim to compile doesn't compile.

Comment: I changed the string** to string[][] and my error was that when i called the function i used `horizontal_Check1(string[][])`instead of `horizontal_Check1(string)` so thank you @xvnm

Comment: @chris WOW, It clearly doesn't, I did not expect that. I will fix the answer.